# Bluetooth headphone volume buttons make big steps

Tags: bluetooth, volume

When I change music volume using the volume buttons on my bluetooth headphones, each click moves the volume 2 or 3 volume steps (compared to when I change volume using the volume buttons on my phone itself). This often means that it jumps right from too loud to too quiet, so I have to dig out my phone to get the volume to a comfortable level.

I've already tried Developer Options > Disable absolute volume, which didn't seem to make any difference. I'm using a Pixel 2 (stock Android 11) with Soundcore Life Q20 headphones.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same prob (with a Samsung, Android 14) and tried this option, too (which is the only hint I found yet). The option is effective only after disabling bluetooth and reconnecting afterwards.
But for me the effect is that volume control is not at all effective on my BT device (except setting zero volume works).